# stack chart with category floated left

Tags: html, css, charts, markup

I'm playing with CSS divs as a chart and I'm trying to make a stacked chart where the div equals 100% of the width of a div and the left portion of the bar is one color and the other portion of the bar is another. Right now I have:

```css
.chart div {
  font: 25px sans-serif;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
  <div style="width: 49.81%;">1, $4,980,777</div>
  <div style="width: 41.10%;">2, $4,109,778</div>
</div>
```

Here is the https://jsfiddle.net/j63grq88/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: inline-block;` to both divs

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```css
.chart{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.chart div {
  font: 25px sans-serif;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.chart div:after{
  content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
  <div style="width: 49.81%;">1, $4,980,777</div>
  <div style="width: 41.10%;">2, $4,109,778</div>
</div>
```